# Remove a frame from a QWidget in a QStackedLayout

Tags: c++11, qt5

How to remove an internal frame from a `QWidget` that was added to a `QWidget::layout()`? I was trying to set `setContetntMargins(0,0,0,0);` but this did not work, but if I set `setContetntMargins(10,10,10,10);` I can see changes.

```
void riseUpWidget(QWidget* widget)
{
    if (layout()->indexOf(widget) == -1)
    {
        layout()->addWidget(widget);
    }

    layout()->setCurrentWidget(widget);
}

QStackedLayout* layout() const
{
    return static_cast<QStackedLayout*>(QWidget::layout());
}
```

[image]

Comment: Concerning layout [`setContentsMargins()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#setContentsMargins) is the proper function (and I've used it successfully in the past). If there is still an unintended margin left, I would look at parent and child widget.

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] to demonstrate your issue? (Sorry, I cannot open your image - company firewall is blocking, but if still open, I could've a look at home on it - later.)

Comment: @Scheff ok thank you. I think I will try to workaround `setContentsMargins()`

Comment: What class are the resp. parent and child widget of the `QStackedLayout` in quest?

Comment: @Scheff all Classes are inherited from `QWidget`. The resp class is `dialog`

Comment: @Scheff well `setContentsMargins(-2,-2,-2,-2)` did the trick, but the solution is kinda hacky. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it is. I'm still convinced that the frame of 2 pixels is caused by child or parent widget of that `QStackedLayout`. I had a look into `QWidget` and `QDialog` but couldn't find anything suspicious. What OS (window manager) are you using?

Comment: I just had a look onto your image. The parent and child widget of that `QStackedLayout` look like `QFrame`s with `Plain` `StyledPanel` shadow. (You should've mentioned that. Any widget in Qt is inherited from `QWidget`.) There is a property [`QFrame::frameWidth`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qframe.html#frameWidth-prop) which might be worth to play with. Another option could be [`QFrame::frameRect`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qframe.html#frameRect-prop) but I would recommend to start with the former.

Comment: @Scheff, okay, it could be the solution, will try it out